# Can I safely copy vmdk disk while VM is still running?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, vmdk

I have a virtual machine in QEMU with snapshots (*vmdk*-disk) and I need to have a clone of that machine in another host. But I can't shutdown this VM for some reasons and can't clone it through the QEMU-cloning because it is extremely huge (there are no space on disk).
So can I just copy that `*.vmdk` to USB flash drive while VM is still running and then properly import this disk in QEMU on another host? Or will it be in some inconsistent state?

Comment: You won’t have the latest changes.  You need to make room on the disk.

Comment: @Ramhound What exactly last changes? I'll be fine with the state for the last OS launch.

Comment: If you don’t care about the changes you can forcefully power off the virtual machine which is like pulling the plug on the device.  However, you really should just make room for the changes, I presume this is a VM that is in production and you can’t take any risk.

Comment: @Ramhound *"power off the virtual machine"* - I can't do that. It must remain running. It is important for production infrastructure.

Comment: You should figure out a way to shut down the virtual machine to prevent further damage. ALL machines have to turn off at some point.

Comment: No; It’s not safe to do what your asking